# Access pass data object from angularJS to php

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm new to angularJS and I am impressed by it. That's why I'm doing a self-study on it and this maybe a duplicate question so sorry guys.

my problem is that how can I access the object that I pass from angular to php....

here's my code:

**ANGULAR**

```
$scope.login = function(){
    console.log($scope.users);
    $http({
        method:'POST',
        url:'db/connection.php',
        data: $scope.users,
        headers:{'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
    }).success(function(res){
        console.log(res);
    }).error(function(error){
        console.log(error);
    });
};
```

**PHP**

```
  <?php
       //access the pass objects here.
       //i've tried using `$_POST['username']` but give me undefined error.
       //and i have also tried echoing on the php file to see if it returns a value and it's working.
```

**CONSOLE LOG**

```
Object {username: "sampleuser", password: "samplepass"}
controller.js:15 <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: username in    <b>D:\xamp\htdocs\angularjs\db\connection.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
```

thanks in advance guys.

Comment: can you please add output of your console.log statements?

Comment: @SomeOne I have put my console.log there.

Comment: can you try something like `data: 'username='+$scope.users.username+'&password='+scope.users.password` and see it that works ?

Comment: I have solve it sir.. I use `JSON.stringify` then I access it on `php` via `json_decode`.

Comment: this is what I was suspecting when suggesting to send form data this way. (y)